# NSTextView inspector bar crash on Sierra 10.12

Tags: cocoa, appkit

Is anyone else seeing a crash calling setUsesInspectorBar on NSTextView for Sierra (release build)? This code worked just fine on 10.11.5 but crashes in AppKit on Sierra. I thought it was a beta version bug I'm still getting it on the full release.

Here's the back trace from lldb.

```
(lldb) bt
* thread #1: tid = 0x76deb, 0x9ecfe013 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 19, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xa007cc0f)
  * frame #0: 0x9ecfe013 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 19
    frame #1: 0x95c5f861 Foundation`releasingRelinquish + 29
    frame #2: 0x95c22636 Foundation`-[NSConcreteMapTable removeObjectForKey:] + 127
    frame #3: 0x92fbec6e AppKit`-[NSStackViewContainer removeView:] + 102
    frame #4: 0x92798554 AppKit`-[NSStackView _insertView:atIndex:inGravity:animated:] + 212
    frame #5: 0x9279847b AppKit`-[NSStackView insertView:atIndex:inGravity:] + 40
    frame #6: 0x9279839b AppKit`-[NSStackView addView:inGravity:] + 78
    frame #7: 0x92f5ec2c AppKit`-[__NSInspectorBarView addItem:] + 71
    frame #8: 0x929281c1 AppKit`__23-[NSInspectorBar _tile]_block_invoke + 303
    frame #9: 0x94566871 CoreFoundation`__53-[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]_block_invoke + 81
    frame #10: 0x94566717 CoreFoundation`-[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 167
    frame #11: 0x945665f5 CoreFoundation`-[NSArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:] + 53
    frame #12: 0x92925e95 AppKit`-[NSInspectorBar _tile] + 484
    frame #13: 0x92924e3d AppKit`-[NSInspectorBar _update] + 224
    frame #14: 0x92630b28 AppKit`-[NSTextView updateInspectorBar] + 71
    frame #15: 0x9263159b AppKit`-[NSTextView updateRuler] + 2622
    frame #16: 0x9292440f AppKit`-[NSTextView(NSSharing) setUsesInspectorBar:] + 350
    frame #17: 0x0014eef4 DockShelf`"-[TTextEditorWindowController awakeFromNib]"(self=0x0073ecc0, _cmd="awakeFromNib") + 116 at UTextEditor_2.pas:124
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in AppKit with 32-bit apps. Unfortunately, not workaround-able (without removing inspector bar support) and will require a fix in AppKit.

---

This should be fixed with 10.12.2

Comment: Yes, that's it! I need to update some ancient code to 64 bit but I guess it's time. I'm pretty sure this was 10.12+ so Apple may have this on the to-do list but it could also be neglected for months or years...

Comment: Reported to Apple: http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=5005564551626752 - includes demo project. (Hint: If someone knew about this bug already during the 10.12 beta and did not report it to Apple - shame on you!)

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove NSTextView component in IB and then insert it back again from component's palette. It is possible that your old XIB file contains some keywords which are not recognised/compiled properly into NIB file and Sierra cannot process file.

Comment: I tried moving the NSTextView (contained in NSScrollView) from the window in the XIB and added it back but that doesn't seem to help. The inspector bar was set from code anyways using setUsesInspectorBar so I didn't expect this to be related.